# How do I extend an EBS volume in Windows

Tags: amazon-web-services

While extending an Amazon EBS volume I am not getting extend option in Windows disk management.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Choose the instance you want to expand, choose the Description tab, and then choose the volume listed for Block devices.
2. Choose the EBS ID.
3. Choose the volume, choose Actions, and then choose Modify Volume.
   After modification I got new un-allocated drive but extend option is disabled.

[sanapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCzAd.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run the **Disk Management tool**, right-click the volume and select **Extend Volume**.

See: [Extending a Windows File System after Resizing a Volume - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-windows.html)

Comment: The extend option is disable means i am not able to click on it. See it in snapshot